# C++ can not link to symbol with prefix __imp_

Tags: c++, c, dll, linker-errors

I wrote a C++ program with Visual Studio. I calls a third-party lib and the problem is the link error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__xxx_init referenced in function _wmain
```

Wondering if the symbol realy exist, I check the lib file with **dumpbin -linkermeber:1** and get the result:

```
 E850 __imp_xxx_init
 E850 xxx_init
```

This is how the symbol is declared:

```
#define E_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
E_API int xxx_init();
```

My Question: How can I make my code link to **__imp_xxx_init** instead of **__imp__xxx_init**

Comment: Check that you're not mixing 32-bit with 64-bit. If not, provide a [mcve].

Comment: It should be undefined, the missing symbol has one too many _ underscores.  `xxx_init()` is decorated to `_xxx_init` since it uses the cdecl calling convention.  The function pointer name that dllimport generates is prefixed with `__imp`.  How this happened is impossible to guess, xxx is too weird a name unless somebody is in the pr0n business and probably obfuscated from the real name.